# BigQuery, Get array of rows number by condition in a group by

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a table

```
id column1 timestamp
1  no
1  yes
1  yes
2  no
2  yes
2  no
```

I need a list of rows number of column1 by condition 'yes' in a group by as

```
   id arr
    1 [2,3]
    2 [2]
```

thanks

Comment: What determines the values of 2, 3, and 2? Rows in a table have no inherent ordering.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard- the row number in the group by id

Comment: But how do you determine the row number? For example, for the `id` value of `2`, it's not clear how to determine the order of `no`, `yes`, `no`. Without a column that you can use for ordering, there is no way to distinguish this from `no`, `no`, `yes`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 pos, 'no' col1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 'no' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 6, 'no' 
)
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(num ORDER BY num) arr
FROM (
  SELECT id, col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pos) num
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE col1 = 'yes'
GROUP BY id
```

with output

```
Row id  arr  
1   1   2    
        3    
2   2   2
```

Note: you MUST have some extra column that would identify order of your rows so output will be deterministic - in this case I added column `pos`. But this can be something like date or timestamp etc.

Obviously, formally you can do something like below with no extra col as in your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'no' col1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'no' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'no' 
)
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(num ORDER BY num) arr
FROM (
  SELECT id, col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) num
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE col1 = 'yes'
GROUP BY id
```

but output will not be deterministic so will have no practical value

Note: in above example you still will have same output as in first query, but in real life if will be random - unless as in first query you have something to determine order

Comment: You are right, I have timestamp column for order by, Thanks!